# Display images with matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I wanna display in a list of lists the images inside it using matplotlib. So for example I wanna have in the first row, the images of the first list, the second row, the images of the second list and so on. I tried this, but I obtain the images in each row, maybe because it will call over and over again subplot. How can I fix it?

```
index_plot=0
for query in list_plot:
    for qm_images in query:
        plt.subplot(3,5,index_plot+1)    
        plt.imshow(np.array(Image.open(qm_images)))
        plt.show()
        index_plot += 1
```

Comment: Can you add the actual output in the post itself?

Comment: Done, as you can see, I want that each list must be displayed in one row, so for first list, first row, second list, second row and so on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of creating many subplots initially create a nested list of `subplots` with `plt.subplots()`, call imshow on each axis

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, axs = plt.subplots(3, 6)

for i, query in enumerate(list_plot):
    for j, qm_images in enumerate(query:
        axs[i][j].imshow(np.array(Image.open(qm_images)))

plt.show()
```

Comment: All correct, just need to do fig, axs = plt.subplots(3, 6) or it will get index error

Comment: Oops yeah I miscounted the number of elements in each list. I'll fix that in the answer.